# How to set Cycles Viewport Rendered Mode to use Tiles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, gpu, tilesize

I have heard questions about the Cycles rendered view being faster than the finished render, for reasons such as Subdivision levels, caustics, and other slow functions that are disabled in the viewport.

However, I personally have the opposite question. My viewport render is rather slow, as it renders the whole viewport as one tile, which my MSI GT 730 doesn't handle well.

I know you can set the final render to progressive as opposed to tiled, but is there a way to set the viewport render to use tiles, such as the Pixar software "It"? This would be then easier on a GPU's limited memory

Comment: As far as I know this isn't currently possible, I think. Try using a small render border instead, and zoom the view out before previewing

Comment: The viewport has all the same stuff enabled as the final render. To make the viewport render faster, you'll have to disable stuff manually (presets can be useful here)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I wonder if there'll ever be a function added to Blender for this...